# How to mock SpringSecurity and OncePerRequestFilter (JWT Authentication Filter) to get @AuthenticationPrincipal?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-test

can anyone tell me how to mock SpringSecurity and OncePerRequestFilter (JWT Authentication Filter)?

There are examples on the Internet, but something I can not collect all together.

So, there is SpringBoot 2.0.
There is a user who comes from @AuthenticationPrincipal as function parameter.

There is a JWtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter which checks the validity of the jwt token.

Necessary

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = NfaBackendApplication.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class })
public class OfferControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository kvUserRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter = new JWTAuthenticationFilter();

    @Mock
    private JWTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test(enabled = true)
    public void getExternalOffers() throws Exception
    {

//        KVUserDetails user = new KVUserDetails("mail@mail.ua", "test", false, true, AuthorityUtils
//            .createAuthorityList("ADMIN"));
//        TestingAuthenticationToken testingAuthenticationToken = new TestingAuthenticationToken(user, null);
//        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(testingAuthenticationToken);

        MockFilterChain filterChain = new MockFilterChain();
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
        request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Authorized");
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
        when(jwtTokenProvider.validateToken("Authorized")).thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/admin/offers")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Tell me please the working example how to wet SpringSecurity and OncePerRequestFilter (JWT Authentication Filter)?

That at request there will come the user which AuthenticationPrincipal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@WithUserDetails` to initialize user for MockMvc test. No need to mock servlet filter.

Something like this:

```
@Test(enabled = true)
@WithUserDetails("mail@mail.ua")
public void getExternalOffers() throws Exception
{
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have perhaps the full sample code?

Comment: Code sample added